# ReactJS list of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in JS and ReactJS.
I tried to implement a list of boxes as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function GenreBox() {
    let [input, setInput] = useState('')
    let [repr, setRepr] = useState('')

    let getClick = () => {
        fetch(`/genre/${input}`).then(
            (res) => res.json().then(
                (data) => { console.log(data); setRepr(data.repr) }
            )
        )
    }

    return (<div>
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={getClick}>Get</button>
        <p>repr: {repr}</p>
    </div>
    )
}

function GenreBoxList() {
    let [genreBoxList, setGenreBoxList] = useState([])
    let [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

    let insertGenreBox = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(index);
        let t = [...genreBoxList];
        t.splice(index, 0, <GenreBox />);
        console.log(t);
        setGenreBoxList(t);
    }
    let removeGenreBox = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let t = [...genreBoxList];
        t.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(t);
        setGenreBoxList(t);
    }
    let indexChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIndex(e.target.value)
    }
    return (<div>
        <button onClick={insertGenreBox}>+</button>
        <button onClick={removeGenreBox}>-</button>
        <input type='number' value={index} onChange={indexChange} />
        <ol>
            {genreBoxList.map((x) => <li>{x}</li>)}
        </ol>
    </div>)
}

export { GenreBox, GenreBoxList }
```

When I click the + and - button with index == 0,
I expect the front of the list to be modified.
However, it appears that no matter what number I set the index to,
it is always operating on the tail of the list...

What am I doing wrong or is this a bad design practice?

EDIT 1:
OK, it seems to be the problem with the key. React seems to treat objects with the same type and key to be equal and hence does not update the page.

EDIT 2:
Now I have added keys to both  and

and it seems to be functioning correctly. So is this how react is proposed to be used?

```
function GenreBoxList() {
    let [genreBoxList, setGenreBoxList] = useState([])
    let [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
    let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

    let insertGenreBox = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(index);
        let t = [...genreBoxList];
        t.splice(index, 0, <GenreBox key={counter} ></GenreBox>);
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        console.log(t);
        setGenreBoxList(t);
    }
    let removeGenreBox = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let t = [...genreBoxList];
        t.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(t);
        setGenreBoxList(t);
    }
    let indexChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIndex(e.target.value)
    }
    return (<div>
        <button onClick={insertGenreBox}>+</button>
        <button onClick={removeGenreBox}>-</button>
        <input type='number' value={index} onChange={indexChange} />
        <ol>
            {genreBoxList.map((x) => <li key={x.key}>{x}</li>)}
        </ol>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add key to `GenreBox`. The `li` element is a container, **react** only takes care of the key on the `li` element. Actually, the code you wrote should work as you want.

Comment: @kanvil Thanks for your comment! You referred to 'container', does that mean <li> does appear in the returned HTML file but <GenreBox> does not? So, react check that when I click the + button, does the <li key=?> list changes according to key(s), and if it does, it will rerender the page, otherwise, it does not. Since I previously does not involve a key, react detects that no change has been made to <li> list since no key is given. Do these statements make sense in a general way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realized in your edit, the key here is `key`.

Your list is an array of items where each item is created by the expression `<GenreBox {...props} />` (which is in fact translated into `React.createElement(GenreBox, props)` ). When React sees an array of such, say, 10 items - it has no way to know which of them was added first. All it knows is that there are 10 of them.

For a moment, let's ignore the fact that the code later wraps each of them inside it's own `<li>` element, and assume we are rendering the array as-is into the `<ol>` container.

React sees there are 10 items of the component that should be rendered, and it invokes the rendering function for each. That function also uses state via `useState()` so React has to pass the correct state to each render. React looks in the state data remained from the previous render, and sees that there are 9 sets of state data since there were only 9 items in the previous render. How would it associate each set of state data to a component in the list? The only way would be to provide the first set of state data to the first item, the second set to the second item, etc. and leave the last item to initialize it's own new state.

By providing a unique `key` attribute, on the other hand, you are giving the item an *identity*. React would now be able to associate the item with the correct set of state data (and other hooks data as well) regardless of it's position in the list.
(In fact, even if you don't provide a key React would provide one, but this key would simply be the index of the item so everything said above still apply).

Lastly, since the code later maps the original array to a new array where each item is wrapped inside a `<li>` element, the actual relevant list is this list of `<li>` items, so the key should be provided there - as you indeed did.

##### Reference:

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: Yes, I realised that after reading the tutorial: '''Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity'''.  I will have a look at the reference you provided! Many thanks!